# Selenoid - Unable to create browser session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, selenoid

I have deployed selenoid on gcp and am able to connect to selenoid UI but I cannot create a session using `http://<vm-ip>:4444/hub/wd` and it gives timeout error. I am also getting timeout error when I request `http://<vm-ip>:4444/status`. Any ideas on what I might be missing here since selenoid UI is running fine on `http://<vm-ip>:8080/#/` I don't understand what could be wrong with browser connection?

Comment: If you are running a virtual machine in cloud platform - this could be because of firewall rules. By default in certain cloud platforms only ports 80, 8080 and 443 are open by default and you have to adjust so called "security groups", i.e. open ports in firewall.

Comment: I have applied the firewall rule to the vm instance that allow all connection. I am able to see the selenoid ui though but I cannot connect to webbrowser.